# How can I run fire quartz trigger in cluster on one instance only

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a clustered environment of Spring Boot instances. The instance is scheduled to send email once a day and I'm using Quartz Job Scheduler for that. However the email is being sent by all instances and I need it to be sent by only one instance. Is it possible to configure the Quartz Scheduler to fire a job on only one instance, I don't care which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look also on this project for your case:

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

Answer (score 0):

Before creating JobDetail object your Job have to be with annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution. This is a mark that you need to run Job on one instance only.